# Calling a row of a table in python

Tags: python, pandas, datatable, export-to-excel, tabula

I extracted a table from python using tabula and have the table printed. I named the table 'test' so when I use
ptint(test) it returns the table:

| Year | Last | First |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | Doe | Jane |
| 2003 | Smith | John |
| 2008 | Ludlow | Edward |
| 2020 | Peterson | Andrew |

Where Jane Doe is row 0 and Andrew Peterson is row 3.
Instead of printing the whole table, can I just print the row with John Smith?
Can I also print just the column with the first names?

Thank you!

Comment: `tabula.read_pdf` returns *list of pandas DataFrames or dict*, just check `print(type(test))`

Comment: `print(test[(test.First=='John') & (test.Last=='Smith')],test.First, sep='\n\n')`

Comment: Instead of specifying the header name like 'First' and 'Last', is there a way to call it based on the row number? (i.e. row 0 is the row for 2001 | Doe | Jane)

Comment: refer [DataFrame.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)